# Integral on a domain $D$

Tags: real-analysis

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_D y(x+e^x) dx dy dz\;\text{ with }D=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2-
> z^2+1\ge0,|y|\le 1-x^2\}.$$

Is the integral null because the function is odd in $y$ and the domain is symmetric in $x$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The area is symmetric about $x=0$ but not clear for integration.